# Drawing on video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I'm trying to get some blocks of colour overlayed/burnt into video with ffmpeg. A bit like a watermark, I suppose but not a logo, just a block of color.

I've looked at using the drawbox function, which appears to me as if it's only applicable to creating images, not video. Alternatively, I could layer an image on the video.

Has anyone got experience with this sorta thing?

Comment: It appears as though filters need to be in the build, hence why drawbox hasn't been working? Anyone to confirm whether drawbox will work for outlined is still a useful element of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf "color=red@0.5:50x50 [c]; [in][c] overlay=10:10" out.avi
```

That should overlay a semitransparent red square on the video.  See the documentation for [`color`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#color) and [`overlay`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#overlay) for more information.